# Effect of sigmas inequality on sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

We have two nets of complex numbers $\{z_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I},\{w_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ for some set $I$ which might be uncountable, and we have
$$\sum_{\alpha\in I}|w_\alpha|\leq d<\sum_{\alpha\in I}|z_\alpha|\leq c$$ for some real numbers $c,d\in R$. Now can we find two nets of complex numbers$\{\tilde{z}_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I},\{\tilde{w}_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ with
$$\sum_{\alpha\in I}|\tilde{w}_\alpha|=\sum_{\alpha\in I}|w_\alpha|,\qquad\sum_{\alpha\in I}|\tilde{z}_\alpha|=\sum_{\alpha\in I}|z_\alpha|,\qquad |\tilde{w}_\alpha|\leq|\tilde{z}_\alpha|,\ (\alpha\in I)$$

or at least 
$$\sum_{\alpha\in I}|w_\alpha|\leq\sum_{\alpha\in I}|\tilde{w}_\alpha|\leq d<\sum_{\alpha\in I}|z_\alpha|\leq\sum_{\alpha\in I}|\tilde{z}_\alpha|\leq c\qquad |\tilde{w}_\alpha|\leq|\tilde{z}_\alpha|,\ (\alpha\in I).$$

Comment: If $I$ is uncountable these are not sequences.  The sum of uncountably many strictly positive numbers is $+\infty$.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. If $I$ be uncountable then the inequality  $\sum_{\alpha\in I}|z_\alpha|\leq c$ implies except countable amounts of $z_\alpha$s rest of them must be zero. Thanks for advising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $\tilde{w}_\alpha = t |z_\alpha|$, $\tilde{z}_\alpha = z_{\alpha}$ where $t = 
\sum_{\alpha} |w_\alpha|/\sum_{\alpha} |z_\alpha|$.

Comment: You solved it impressively.Thanks